# Childpage title + content on Parent Page

Tags: pages, child-pages

Currently I'm trying to make a dynamic bootstrap collapse with child page information. The problems I'm facing is how to get the_content(); (it's all text without a read more option) of a child page and how can I make div ID's unique?

```
<h1>Themas</h1>
<div class="row">
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">

<?php
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>


<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle" href="#UNIQUEID" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
</h4>
</div>                  
<div id="#UNIQUEID" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body"><?php echo $pageChild->post_content; ?></div>
</div>
</div>



<?php endforeach; endif;
?>

</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rarely ever need a custom SQL query, use the tools WordPress has to offer:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order post_title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>

        <div id="page-<?php the_ID() ?>">
            <?php the_content() // Use any template tags as you would normally ?>       
        </div>

    <?php endwhile ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata() // Restore the current page ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the correct answer. I'll post the total code under this answer.

Comment: @rwzdoorn I'd say don't worry - this answer sufficiently explains the concept, your exact code is unlikely to be relevant for anyone else.